# OneToMany relation returns duplicated items & lacks some items

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I'm currently starting a new Spring boot project, which uses  a relational database:
I have a "kit" object which has multiple images:
here's the kit object code

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Table(name = "kits")
public class Kit {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private UUID id;

private String name;
private String description;
private Integer quantity;
private Integer quantityReserved;
private Integer quantityLent;
private File pdf;

@Builder.Default
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "kit")
private Collection<KitImage> images = new ArrayList<>();

private String link;


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, o);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

}`

and the kitImage object:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Table(name = "kit_image")
public class KitImage {
@Id
UUID kitId;

@MapsId
@NonNull
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "kit_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
Kit kit;

byte[] image;


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, o);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

}

this is the tiny code for the repo, for now i only use the findAll method
[image]

Here are the migrations used for the db creation:

```
CREATE TABLE kits
(
    id                uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid(),
    name              TEXT NOT NULL,
    description       TEXT,
    link              TEXT        NOT NULL,
    quantity          INTEGER     NOT NULL default 0,
    quantity_lent     INTEGER     NOT NULL default 0,
    quantity_reserved INTEGER     NOT NULL default 0,
    pdf               bytea,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE kit_image
(
    kit_id                uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid(),
    image               bytea,
    PRIMARY KEY (kit_id, image),
    FOREIGN KEY (kit_id) REFERENCES kits(id)
);
```

The kits are well-retrieved but the images linked are not. I got the wright amount of images but they are all the first row duplicated as many time as needed

Any thoughts on this one ? thks

Edit: [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you create your data and does it look as you would expect when viewing the db-tables?

Comment: datas are manually inserted in base for now, i'll update my post with the data

Comment: The only thing I notice is, that the data you provided doesn't match with the JSON response. Is that expected or is this the issue at hand?
Number of results seems fine to me

Comment: That's my exact issue: data does not match but result count does

Comment: Ah, I see. I have some Ideas, but nothing definitive. I'll try to reproduce this issue later today and will get back to you

Comment: this issue is fixed, i was lacking an id for the images